# Got Pacman instead of circle when buffering point QGIS 2.14 standalone C++ application

Tags: qgis, buffer, c++, qt, circle

```
QgsVectorLayer *circleLayer = new QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "Circle", "memory");

QgsFeature circleFeature = QgsFeature();

circleFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry::fromPoint(geometryPoint)->buffer(10000,20));

QgsVectorDataProvider *circleDataProvider = circleLayer->dataProvider();
QgsFeatureList circleFeatureList = QgsFeatureList();
circleFeatureList.append(circleFeature);

if(!circleDataProvider->addFeatures(circleFeatureList)){
    qDebug()<<"Error adding feature!";
    return;
}

circleLayer->updateExtents();

QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2 *circleLayerRenderer = new QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(QgsSymbolV2::defaultSymbol(circleLayer->geometryType()));
circleLayer->setRendererV2(circleLayerRenderer);

QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(circleLayer, TRUE);
mainLayerSet.push_front(circleLayer);
mpMapCanvas->setLayerSet(mainLayerSet);
mpMapCanvas->refresh();
mpMapCanvas->zoomToFullExtent();
```

makes Pacman (cuts off last segment of circle) instead of circle in my standalone application. Is this a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to add the vector layer without set a layer renderer ?

Comment: yes, same result.

Comment: What are your CRS, units ?

Comment: EPSG:3857, meters. Tested on EPSG:4326 with degrees, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using translateFeature() instead of moveVertex(). Works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I am working on QGIS 3.6, I've translated your code in Python 3 (few changes from PyQgis 2.x, for example `fromPoint`, `QgsPoint` and `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()`) and it's working perfectly :

```
circleLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:3857", "Circle", "memory")

circleFeature = QgsFeature()
circleFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(1000, 1000)).buffer(10000, 20))

circleDataProvider = circleLayer.dataProvider()
if not circleDataProvider.addFeature(circleFeature):
    raise Exception("Error adding feature!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(circleLayer, True)
```

Can you try this in your QGIS installation with the few code modification ?

Comment: I've tried to do this before and it really works fine in QGIS Desktop application.

Comment: I have few ideas left : that the first and last pair of coordinates of `QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(1000, 1000)).buffer(10000, 20).asWkt()` are the same, `circleLayer.getFeature(1).geometry().asWkt()` equals `QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(1000, 1000)).buffer(10000, 20).asWkt()`, and finally, is there working on an updated version of QGIS, like 2.18 if you want to stay in 2.x versions ?